# Restrict RDP access to 1 public ip address. Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I have a server who runs Windows Server 2012 R2. I would like to restrict the access of the RDP only to 1 public ip address.

I tried the "Firewall with advanced security" --> Inbound Rules --> Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-IN) --> Properties --Scope --> Remote IP address, i add my static ip address, but still i can access RDP from everywhere.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you created a DENY rule for NOT your IP?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where exactly should i create a deny rule? At the RDP?

Comment: If you remove your existing rule can you still connect from any IP? If so then your rule is applying an already open rule - i.e. not going to work. If you create a Windows firewall DENY rule for all addresses APART from your public IP (targeted at your RDP port) then this should block everything BUT your IP... if you see what I mean...

Comment: Hello, I can't test it that because it is a server hosted in another country and i have access only via RDP. I just want to be able and connect on it only my static IP address.

Comment: If you can access the server via RDP then you can access the server's `Control Panel` to get to `Windows Firewall`... Just be very careful using DENY rules as it can ultimately lead to  you being locked out of your own server if you get it wrong... we can only help so much because we don't know whether your server config has any pre-existing rules that aren't default.

Comment: Yes i can access the Control panel and actually i can create a rule at the Windows Firewall. The thing is that when i create a deny rule, i can't set exception and this occur to be locked out! The i ask my hosting provider to restore my access!! Any idea how to create deny rule with exception?